# Mongo return data based on nested date params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm scraping and saving a bunch of data into a mongodb collection by pushing it into an array, an example of the saved data looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("616eafce1e7edf6e9b033938"), 
    "collectibleId" : "34e05c2c-19dd-4509-a98c-bb11cd275d34", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-19T11:45:16.845+0000"), 
    "history" : [
        {
            "storePrice" : 6.99, 
            "value" : NumberInt(27), 
            "date" : ISODate("2021-10-19T11:45:16.683+0000"), 
            "totalListings" : NumberInt(904), 
            "hourlyChange" : {
                "market" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }, 
        {
            "storePrice" : 6.99, 
            "value" : 27.5, 
            "date" : ISODate("2021-10-19T11:59:01.192+0000"), 
            "totalListings" : NumberInt(902), 
            "hourlyChange" : {
                "market" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }, 
        ... loads more items ...
   ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-27T18:59:01.109+0000")
}
```

I'm trying to now write a query for the data that can return only the recorded data within a specific timeframe. So far I've tried this:

```
Prices.findOne({
        collectibleId: slug,
        history: {
            date: {
                $gte: new Date("2021-10-26T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    }).exec((err, data) => {
        if (err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            })
        }
        res.json(data)
    })
```

But the result im getting is always null. I'm wondering if it's because date is nested in history and perhaps im writing that wrong ? Any advice appreciated thank you.

Comment: Your document doesn''t have the field you are trying to query on: `collectibleId: slug`

Comment: Thanks, I actually have two collections, the data example uses uniqueCoverId, i'll update to collectibleId but the data aside from that one point is the same. If i take out the history filter the query does return all documents

Comment: Try using the _dot notation_ as shown in this documentation: [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$match` then `$set`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      collectibleId: "slug",
      "history.date": {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-10-26T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "history": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$history",
          "as": "h",
          "cond": {
            $gte: [
              "$$h.date",
              ISODate("2021-10-26T00:00:00.000Z")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q0JACWGjo9W)